# Prolog and Closed Formulas

Tags: first-order-logic

Why in Prolog the use of First Order Logic is limited to closed formulas ?

Is is due to some worttwhile properties of closed formula ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Because only closed formulas are *sentences*, i.e. have meaning.

Comment: Why is not possible to give an interpretation for a not closed formula ?

Comment: ps: that also means that when we use deduction rules (for example inference, or axiom schemas) we are considering only closed formulas, am i correct ?

Comment: In order to interpret an *open* formula we have to assume a sort of "context" for the free variables, i.e. a "temporary denotation" for them, like the way to give meaning to the statement "It is red". This can be done technically with the variables assignment mechanism.

Comment: Axioms are usually Closed formulas; inference rules use also open ones.

Comment: If we make the statement that X went to the store to buy Y. Is that true or false?